# Unexpected token : in JSON at position 8

Tags: json

Can anyone say what the problem is with this code that I got next error Unexpected token: in JSON at position 8

```
JSON.parse(`"${id}" : [ ${v}, ${ this.state[id][1] } || ${ this.props.filterValues[id][1] } ]`),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have opening and close `{}`
     `` JSON.parse(`{"${id}" : [ ${v}, ${ this.state[id][1] } || ${ this.props.filterValues[id][1] } ]}`), ``

Comment: Already done it. But have the same error in a position where this.state started. Any thoughts?

Comment: Its hard to tell, can you print out what "${id}" is returning. That may be whats in the 8th position.

Comment: I just reread your comment, and the only thing i can think of is that ```id``` might need to have quotes around it, depending on if its a variable of if it is a obj with key 'id' inside your state. ```this.state['id'][1]```